# Jumping to source w/ Carthage

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

When I used Cocoapods I could jump to the definition of some library function.  Now I'm using Carthage.  When I jump to definition, it sometimes errors, but if it succeeds it takes me to what appears to be "generated Swift headers".  these are not helpful as I want to check the actual implementation logic conveniently.